# Installing git documentation packages on RHEL 5

Tags: git, makefile, rhel5, manpage

I am trying to install git 1.8.1 on a RHEL 5 system, and I am having a ton of difficulty dealing with the documentation portion of the build.  Namely, `asciidoc`.  There are problems with the Docbook being really outdated on RHEL5.

So, I would like the use the `make quick-install-doc`, `make quick-install-man` and `make quick-install-html` commands that are specified in the installation readme file.  However, I have absolutely no clue where to actually download the files to make this happen.  According to the readme:

> To use these build targets, you need to
>      clone two separate git-htmldocs and git-manpages repositories next
>      to the clone of git itself.

Where exactly are the "git-htmldocs" and "git-manpages" located?

**EDIT:** I think I found the location of where to get it.

This git url is for the man pages: git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git-manpages.git

This git url is for the html pages: git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git-htmldocs.git

I also found them at this Google Code site: http://code.google.com/p/git-core/downloads/list

Now... How do I install them?  I don't understand what it means when it says: "next to the clone of git itself".  Does this mean *in* the git source directory, or directly outside of it?

Comment: this should help you http://serverfault.com/questions/81362/how-to-install-git-to-red-hat-enterprise-linux-5-3-x64 without recompiling

Comment: I can't use EPEL.  (It's a long story...)

Comment: can't you download just git epel rpms directly and install them using rpm?

Comment: I would like to use the latest version.  I am able to build the binaries OK, I just need the docs.  The one in EPEL is a bit older.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!  These are the instructions for doing it on RHEL 5 for the version 1.8.1:

What you need to do is first build and install git using the commands:

```
$ make prefix=/usr all
$ sudo make prefix=/usr install
```

Once that is installed and done, you then need to `cd` outside of the git source code directory, and clone the docs:

```
$ cd ../
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git-manpages.git
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git-htmldocs.git
```

Next, you then need to navigate back into the git source code directory, and run the commands:

```
$ sudo make prefix=/usr quick-install-doc
$ sudo make prefix=/usr quick-install-html
```

Doing this installed the man pages, and the html page documentation!

Comment: This didn't work for me, but after cloning the repository I just checked out the right version (see `git log`) and ran `sudo cp -r * /usr/local/share/man/`